# SwipeRefreshLayout gesture detection in drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, gesture-recognition

I'm using SwipeRefreshLayout in drawer. When I stat scrolling up and down in the listview the gesture should be straight up and down, If the finger moves just a little bit a side without lifting it up, the scroll gesture stops and starts the gesture for open close the drawer. 
If I'm not using SwipeRefreshLayout, the scroll gesture dose not stops until I lift my finger up.

This is the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh_lisview_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" >

        <views.IndexableListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The code is the same as this one:
http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. You have to "lock" the drawer while  you are scrolling and unlock it again when the scrolling even finish. For that I used 2 things:

1. add an OnScrollListener to your listView like:

   ```
   mDrawerListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
       @Override
       public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
           if (i == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
               mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
           else
               mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
       }

       @Override
       public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i2, int i3) {

       }
   });
   ```
2. To avoid some problems trying to fire "refresh event", you should implement the work around suggested by spencer on this link: [Issue 69074](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69074)