# NavigationDrawer: behaviour with ListView and SwipeRefreshLayout, animation stuck

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, navigation-drawer, mvvmcross

I'm having a NavigationDrawer that includes a SwipeRefreshLayout and a ListView. There are two problems: The first one is, when you pull to refresh and move the NavigationDrawer just one pixel to the left the animation of the SwipeRefreshLayout will stop - the app appears to hang (though everything is working fine).
The 2nd problem is that the NavigationDrawer feels so "floaty" that, when scrolling through the ListView, you sometimes move the drawer and the scrolling in the drawer is blocked.

Here's the Layout (using xamarin.android and mvvmcross):

```
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/categoriesRefresher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    local:MvxBind="Refreshing CategoriesLoading; RefreshCommand ReloadCommand">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/menuListView"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/seperator_line_listview"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Categories; ItemClick CategorySelectedCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/cells_category_item" />
</MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I've tried to block the NavigationDrawer from responding to gestures when the ListView is scrolling:

```
listView.Scroll += ListViewOnScroll;
listView.ScrollStateChanged += ListViewOnScrollStateChanged;

private void ListViewOnScrollStateChanged(object sender, AbsListView.ScrollStateChangedEventArgs scrollStateChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if(scrollStateChangedEventArgs.ScrollState == ScrollState.Idle)
            this.parentActivity.DrawerLayout?.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked);
    }

 private void ListViewOnScroll(object sender, AbsListView.ScrollEventArgs scrollEventArgs)
    {
        this.parentActivity.DrawerLayout?.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeLockedOpen);
    }
```

But this has at least two side-effects: performance on lower-end devices tanks and automatically closing the NavigationDrawer after selecting an item stops working, even when resetting the LockMode:

```
DrawerLayout?.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked);
DrawerLayout?.CloseDrawers();
```

It also does not fix the stuck SwipeRefreshLayout Animation, at least you can't move the drawer while scrolling.

Is there any better way to handle this issue and fix the other ones?

Comment: I take that you have seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25899473/368379 ?